# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UUID'

Tags: node.js, typescript

why I get this error ?

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UUID'.
```

I created a class named uuid and then want it to use it with typescript

UUID.ts

```
// Typescript UUID
export class UUID {
  private str: string;

  constructor(str?: string) {
      this.str = str || UUID.getNewGUIDString();
  }

  toString() {
      return this.str;
  }

  private static getNewGUIDString() {
      // your favourite guid generation function could go here
      // ex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8809472/188246
      let d = new Date().getTime();
      if (window.performance && typeof window.performance.now === "function") {
          d += performance.now(); //use high-precision timer if available
      }
      return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, (c) => {
          let r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
          d = Math.floor(d/16);
          return (c=='x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
      });
  }
}
```

server.ts

```
// type err
const data = await CreateBilling('a1208217-3587-40e1-97ab-695b01cae342');
```

CREATE BILLING

```
const CreateBilling = async (shop_id: UUID) => {
  try {
  // get the categories and remove the same categories
  const data = await ShopGetCategories(shop_id);

  console.log(data);
  return data;
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    Sentry.captureException(e);
    return e;
  }
};

export default CreateBilling;
```

I am thankful for your help I dont know what I am doing wrong how can I solve this issue to use a UUID as type

..........................................................................................................................................................

Comment: UUID is a class you need to construct the class with the uuid string. Change `await CreateBilling('a1208217-3587-40e1-97ab-695b01cae342')` to `await CreateBilling(new UUID('a1208217-3587-40e1-97ab-695b01cae342'))`

Comment: Why do you use custom `uuid` generator? You can use [`crypto.randomUUID`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptorandomuuidoptions) if you use node >=14 or use `uuid` npm package or custom generator if you are using node <14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateBilling()` accepts an argument `shop_id` of type `UUID` which is a class. So you should probably be calling the function as follows and pass the uuid string to the constructor.

```
const data = await CreateBilling(
  new UUID("a1208217-3587-40e1-97ab-695b01cae342")
);
```